# VBA Issue - Trying to Concatenate and Loop

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement

So I need to go to each line, evaluate the string against a list of possible payers, then return the formula for that particular payer. But I keep getting errors, could someone please help me figure out what is wrong with my code? I'm new to progamming and cannot figure out what the issue is.

```
Sub CkNoConcatenate()
'
' CkNoConcatenate Macro
'

'
    Dim x As Range, y As Range, c As String
    rnumbers = Rows(ActiveCell.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range("AL2:AL3000")
    Set y = ActiveSheet.Range("AS2:AS3000")
    
    For Each cell In x
    If c Is "AETNA A04" Or "AETNA AS01" Or "AETNA H09" Or "CIGNA" Or "HUMANA AHP" Or "HUMANA INS CO" Or "HWHO" Or "HHP" Then
    y = FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-7],"" - "",LEFT(RC[4],15))"
    ElseIf c = "AARP SUPPLEMENTA" Or "ANTHEM BLUE IN5C" Or "ANTHEM BLUE IN5F" Or "ANTHEM BLUE O5C" Or "HUMANA GOVT BUSI" Or "MARKETPLACE" Or "MCRIN CLAIMS" Or "OPTUM VA CCN REG" Or "WISCONSIN PHYSIC" Or "UNITEDHEALTHCARE" Or "MANAGED HEALTH" Then
    y = FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-7],"" - "",LEFT(RC[4],10))"
    ElseIf c = "CIGNA EDGE TRANS" Then
    y = FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-7],"" - "",LEFT(RC[4],12))"
    ElseIf c = "GERBER LIFE INS" Or "GPM HEALTH INS" Or "MUTUAL OF OMAHA" Or "OMAHA INS CO" Or "UNITED OF OMAHA" Or "UNITED WORLD" Then
    y = FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-7],"" - "",LEFT(RC[4],28))"
    ElseIf c = "GOLDEN RULE INSU" Then
    y = FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-7],"" - "",LEFT(RC[4],13))"
    ElseIf c = "WPS" Or "HNB - ECHO" Or "UHC GOVERNMENT E" Or "UMR" Or "UMR CITY OF HEND" Or "UMR COMPASS ROSE" Or "UMR FREEDOM MORT" Or "UMR NRECA" Or "UMR PEDCOR MANAG" Or "UMR SMC CORPORAT" Or "UNITED BEHAVIORA" Or "UMR THE CHRISTIA" Or "UMR WABASH NATIO" Then
    y = FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-7],"" - "",LEFT(RC[4],9))"
    Else: y = x
    End If
    Next cell
     
End Sub
```

Comment: Rather than `If c Is "AETNA A04" Or "AETNA AS01" ... ` use `If c.Value = "AETNA A04" Or c.Value = "AETNA AS01" ... `. Neither `Is` nor `Or` work the way you seem to think they do. `y = FormulaR1C1 =` also don't make sense. Perhaps you mean `y.FormulaR1C1 =`, though I doubt that your intention is to set that formula for the entire range `y`.

Comment: I do not believe that multiple assignments is supported in VBA: `y = FormulaR1C1 = ...`

Comment: Where is variable `FormulaR1C1` declared?

Comment: Since `y` is a range `AS2:AS3000`, you are setting the formula to all cells in the range. Is that what you intend?

Comment: I doubt you really mean `y = x`. I don't mean to sound rude, but it might help to work though a book or tutorial on VBA. The code seems like you are developing it trial and error rather than after first getting a basic understanding the syntax and semantics of Excel VBA. Putting this code to the side and spending a few days learning the fundamentals might save time in the long run.

Comment: Note also that you never give `c` a value. You are using `cell` in the loop header but the switching to `c` in the body of the loop. In context `c` should be a `Range` variable rather than a `String` variable.

Answer (score 2):

This pattern would be better I think.

Please heed the advice from @JohnColeman though - if you want to continue with this you need a more-solid understanding of the basics.

```vb
Sub CkNoConcatenate()

    Dim cell As Range, n As Long
    
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("AL2:AL3000").Cells
    
        'how many characters are we extracting?  (Some names omitted for clarity)
        Select Case cell.Value
            Case "AETNA A04", "AETNA AS01", "AETNA H09", "CIGNA"
                n = 15
            Case "AARP SUPPLEMENTA", "ANTHEM BLUE IN5C", "ANTHEM BLUE IN5F"
                n = 10
            Case "CIGNA EDGE TRANS"
                n = 12
            Case "GERBER LIFE INS", "GPM HEALTH INS", "MUTUAL OF OMAHA", "OMAHA INS CO"
                n = 28
            Case "GOLDEN RULE INSU"
                n = 13
            Case "WPS", "HNB - ECHO", "UHC GOVERNMENT E", "UMR", "UMR CITY OF HEND"
                n = 9
            Case Else
                n = 0
        End Select
        
        With cell.EntireRow
            'range addresses below are *relative* to the row
            .Range("AS1").Value = IIf(n = 0, cell.Value, _
                                     .Range("AL1").Value & " - " & Left(.Range("AW1").Value, n))
        End With
    
    Next cell
     
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, this is the first macro I have attempted to write straight out rather than record. I am also learning programming basic from CodeAcademy.  So I am pretty green, will learn a bit more before trying to write one again.

Answer (score 1):

A second answer which shows how to use a scripting.dictionary to simplify your (and Tims Case statement) code.

```
Option Explicit

Const Action1 As String = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-7],"" - "",LEFT(RC[4],15))"
Const Action2 As String = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-7],"" - "",LEFT(RC[4],10))"
Const Action3 As String = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-7],"" - "",LEFT(RC[4],12))"
Const Action4 As String = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-7],"" - "",LEFT(RC[4],28))"
Const Action5 As String = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-7],"" - "",LEFT(RC[4],13))"
Const Action6 As String = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-7],"" - "",LEFT(RC[4],9))"

Private Payers As scripting.Dictionary



Sub CkNoConcatenate()
'
' CkNoConcatenate Macro
'
    ' In the next row you delare c as a string but you never assign a value to it
    Dim x As Range, y As Range, c As String
    
    ' You don't declare rnumbers but also you never use the value
    rnumbers = Rows(ActiveCell.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range("AL2:AL3000")
    Set y = ActiveSheet.Range("AS2:AS3000")
    If Payers Is Nothing Then SetupPayers
    ' Cell is just a Bad bad bad name for a VBA variable as it has potential clashes
    ' with keywords used in the various Office object models
    '  In a for each loop the control variable 'myCell' must be a variant (or a suitable object)
    Dim myCell As Variant
    For Each myCell In x
    
        '  This is where we simplify your complex if/elseif/else/end
        
        If Payers.Exists(Cell.value2) Then
        
            ' I've no idea if the two lines below are what you intended.
            ' replace them with something meaningful.
            ' Others have given you advice on why your original code was incorrrect
            FormulaR1C1 = Payers.Item(Cell.value2)
            y = FormulaR1C1
            
        Else
    
            y = x
         
        End If
        
    Next
     
End Sub



Public Sub SetupPayers()
    
    Set Payers = New scripting.Dictionary
        
    With Payers
    
        'Action1 payers
        .Add "AETNA A04", Action1
        .Add "AETNA AS01", Action1
        .Add "AETNA H09", Action1
        .Add "CIGNA", Action1
        .Add "HUMANA AHP", Action1
        .Add "HUMANA INS CO", Action1
        .Add "HWHO", Action1
        .Add "HHP", Action1
        
        'Action2 payers
        .Add "AARP SUPPLEMENTA", Action2
        .Add "ANTHEM BLUE IN5C", Action2
        .Add "ANTHEM BLUE IN5F", Action2
        .Add "ANTHEM BLUE O5C", Action2
        .Add "HUMANA GOVT BUSI", Action2
        .Add "MARKETPLACE", Action2
        .Add "MCRIN CLAIMS", Action2
        .Add "OPTUM VA CCN REG", Action2
        .Add "WISCONSIN PHYSIC", Action2
        .Add "UNITEDHEALTHCARE", Action2
        .Add "MANAGED HEALTH", Action2
        
        'Action3 payers
        .Add "CIGNA EDGE TRANS", Action3
        
        'Action4 Payers
        .Add "GERBER LIFE INS", Action4
        .Add "GPM HEALTH INS", Action4
        .Add "MUTUAL OF OMAHA", Action4
        .Add "OMAHA INS CO", Action4
        .Add "UNITED OF OMAHA", Action4
        .Add "UNITED WORLD", Action4
        
        'Action5 payers
        .Add "GOLDEN RULE INSU", Action5
        
        'Action6 payers
        .Add "WPS", Action6
        .Add "HNB - ECHO", Action6
        .Add "UHC GOVERNMENT E", Action6
        .Add "UMR", Action6
        .Add "UMR CITY OF HEND", Action6
        .Add "UMR COMPASS ROSE", Action6
        .Add "UMR FREEDOM MORT", Action6
        .Add "UMR NRECA", Action6
        .Add "UMR PEDCOR MANAG", Action6
        .Add "UMR SMC CORPORAT", Action6
        .Add "UNITED BEHAVIORA", Action6
        .Add "UMR THE CHRISTIA", Action6
        .Add "UMR WABASH NATIO", Action6
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```